# First encounter of Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I have been assigned to find a solution to a specific Sturm-Liouville problem as preparation for an upcoming interview. This is in fact the first time I've ever met this class of problems (being a second year mathematics student at university). Anyway I've done some research and had a good crack at the problem but I find myself not knowing whether anything I've done is right.

Here is the phrasing of the question:

> Any linear second order ordinary differential equation can be written in the classical Sturm-Liouville form,
>
> $$L(y(x))=\lambda w(x)y(x),\;x\in[a,b],\;(1)$$
>
> in which the operator, $L$, is self-adjoint. Typically, $(1)$ will be subject to boundary conditions of the form,
>
> $$A_1y(a) + B_1y′(a)=0,\;A_2y(b) + B_2y′(b)=0.\;(2)$$
>
> The solution of $(1)$, subject to $(2)$, gives rise to an infinite set of eigenfunctions, $y_n(x)$, which are orthogonal with respect to one another and the weight function, $w(x)$. Each eigenfunction has an associated, real eigenvalue, $λ_n$.

The conditions we are given to work with are:

> $$L = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + 1,\;x ∈ [0, 1],$$
>   $$w(x) = 1,$$
>   $and,$
>   $$y(0) = 0,\,y'(1) = 0.$$

I am asked to find the analytic solution to this particular Sturm-Liouville problem which I worked out to be:
$$y_n(x) = B_n\sin\left(\left(2n+1\right)\frac{\pi}{2}x\right),\;n\in\mathbb Z$$

where $B_n$ is undetermined.

I am asked to determine $B_n$ by imposing:

> $$\int_0^1y_n^2(x)\,dx=1.$$

Using this I found that $B_n=\pm\sqrt{2},$ which troubles me because in all the examples I've looked at regarding Sturm-Liouville problems a situation like this (where the constants are ambiguous) has not arisen. So I am worried I have made an error somewhere leading up to this. Anyway the next task is to represent $g(x)=x$ as an infinite series using the previously found eigenfunctions over the domain $x\in[0,1].$

Now I searched online for a method to do this and found this document: [Non-homogeneous Sturm-Liouville problems](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m316/nhslp.pdf). Looking at the top of the second page they give a formula for finding the coefficients/weightings to express any function over $[0,1]$ as a series of eigenfunctions. Using this and my eigenfunctions I found that $$x=\frac{8}{\pi ^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}\sin\left(\left(2n+1\right)\frac{\pi}{2}x\right).$$

But I know this is completely wrong as I plotted this sum on MatLab to a sufficient number terms and it looked nothing like the function $g(x)=x$.

Now if you've read this far that is much appreciated and any help you could provide would be fantastic as I really would like to do well in solving this problem. Of course I will continue to research into this topic (I've even bought a textbook on Sturm-Liouville theory!) and will keep this post updated as necessary.

Comment: Also a second year undergraduate student here! [Here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/dbs26/1BMethods/SturmLiouville.pdf) are our notes on Sturm-Liouville theory, which may be useful to you.

Comment: @B.Mehta Thanks a lot for providing those, I'll be sure to read through them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notes on your solution:

- It might be worth noting that you can restrict $n$ to be a
  non-negative integer, since any negative integer will reproduce a
  solution you have already found.
- Typically the normalisation constant $B_n$ is chosen to be positive, since a negative one will just give negative values for coefficients later.  Essentially, the constant doesn't make much difference at all, so we pick a positive one for convenience's sake.
- From Sturm-Liouville theory we have that the eigenfunctions form a *complete* basis for the vector space of functions subject to the same boundary conditions, that is, any function $f$ with $f(0)=f'(1)=0$ can be written as a (probably) infinite linear combination of the eigenfunctions you've found. I'll try to explain what the coefficients should be instead of quoting a formula.

A Sturm-Liouville operator induces an *inner product*, essentially measuring the "angle" between two functions.  In this case $w(x)=1$ so I won't bother with the subscript $w$ that should really be there.  We define the inner product (think the generalisation of dot product) for this problem to be
$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx$$
The useful parts about this are that the operator $L$ is self adjoint with respect to this inner product, namely that $\langle Lf,g\rangle = \langle f,Lg\rangle $, and that eigenfunctions with respect to different eigenvalues are orthogonal, that is if $Lf=\lambda_1 f$ and $Lg=\lambda_2 g$ with $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$ then $\langle f, g \rangle = 0$.  (Both these facts are proved in the notes I gave you in the comments, but it might be useful to prove the first with your specific $L$ instead of the general case.

Now, we'd like to express $x$ in terms of the $y_n$ that you've found.  By completeness, $x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n y_n$, for some undetermined $c_n$.  But look what happens if we take the inner product of both sides with $y_m$, for some $m$:
$$\begin{align}
x &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n y_n \\
\langle x, y_m \rangle &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \langle y_n, y_m \rangle \\
\langle x, y_m \rangle &= c_m \langle y_m, y_m \rangle
\end{align}$$

I subtly used linearity of the inner product in there, which you should justify to yourself from the definition I gave above of the inner product.  Also, I used $\langle y_n, y_m \rangle = 0$ for $n \ne m$, which comes from orthogonality.  So almost all the terms of the sum have disappeared, save for the $\langle y_m, y_m \rangle$.  But you've already *normalised* the $y_m$ to set this equal to $1$! This means that we have a nice expression for $c_m$, which is $\langle x, y_m \rangle$.

Computing this integral on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20x%20sin((2n%2B1)%2F2%20pi%20x)%20from%200%20to%201) because I'm lazy, we have $$c_n = \frac{4 \sqrt{2}}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2}(-1)^n$$
$$x = \frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} \sin\left(\frac{2n+1}{2} \pi x\right)$$

So it looks like the only mistake you made was missing out $n=0$ in the sum, since this solution does converge nicely to $x$ on $[0, 1]$.  Even if the bulk of this post didn't directly solve your problem, I hope it's given you a useful insight into Sturm Liouville theory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it has been invaluable! After altering my MatLab code to include the term $n=0$ in the sum it looks very resemblant of the $g(x)=x$ graph. I'd just like to point out that initially I did not consider this term since the question asks to represent $g(x)$ as a sum from 1 to $\infty$ however this could be a typo in the question. Also you note that any $f$ that can be represented by these eigenfunctions must satisfy $f(0)=f'(1)=0$ however for $g(x)=x$ then $g'(x)=1 \forall x\in [0,1] so this would seem to not satisfy these boundary conditions. Thank you again!

Comment: Correction to my previous comment in the penultimate line: $$g'(x)=1\; \forall x\in [0,1]$$

Comment: To make your expansion have limits $n=1$ to $\infty$, you could just change the $(2n+1)$ terms into $(2n-1)$ and introduce a minus sign!  And it looks like I have some more sturm-liouville studying to do; I should have said that certain nice functions can be.  I think it works for functions in the relevant [$L^p$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Weighted_Lp_space), but in most applications the completeness is swept under the carpet.

Comment: Of course, how did I not think of that! Thank you very much again for your help.